# How do you get the absolute path of a file in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, absolute-path, os.path

I have read quite a few links on the site saying to use "os.path.abspath(#filename)".  This method isn't exactly working for me.  I am writing a program that will be able to search a given directory for files with certain extensions, save the name and absolute path as keys and values (respectively) into a dictionary, and then use the absolute path to open the files and make the edits that are required.  The problem I am having is that when I use os.path.abspath() it isn't returning the full path.

Let's say my program is on the desktop.  I have a file stored at "C:\Users\Travis\Desktop\Test1\Test1A\test.c".  My program can easily locate this file, but when I use os.path.abspath() it returns "C:\Users\Travis\Desktop\test.c" which is the absolute path of where my source code is stored, but not the file I was searching for.

My exact code is:

```
import os
Files={}#Dictionary that will hold file names and absolute paths
root=os.getcwd()#Finds starting point
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.c'):#Look for files that end in .c
            Files[file]=os.path.abspath(file)
```

Any tips or advice as to why it may be doing this and how I can fix it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `os.path` encourages lots of error-prone patterns in your code.  You should probably avoid it as much as you can.  Consider one of the better third-party path libraries (something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filepath/ or even https://pypi.python.org/pypi/strpath)

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: That's nonsense. People don't always understand what is relative and what is absolute, but to claim that `os.path` *encourages lots of error-prone patterns* is ludicrous.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: and if you want to recommend a OO approach to path handling, why not [`pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib)? As of Python 3.4, that's now part of the standard lib.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess it's because I'm ludicrous.

Answer (score 6):

`os.path.abspath()` makes a relative path absolute *relative to the current working directory*, not to the file's original location. A path is just a string, Python has no way of knowing where the filename came from.

You need to supply the directory yourself. When you use `os.walk`, each iteration lists the directory being listed (`root` in your code), the list of subdirectories (just their names) and a list of filenames (again, just their names). Use `root` together with the filename to make an absolute path:

```
Files={}
cwd = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.c'):
            Files[file] = os.path.join(root, os.path.abspath(file))
```

Note that your code only records the *one* path for each unique filename; if you have `foo/bar/baz.c` and `foo/spam/baz.c`, it depends on the order the OS listed the `bar` and `spam` subdirectories which one of the two paths wins.

You may want to collect paths into a list instead:

```
Files={}
cwd = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.c'):
            full_path = os.path.join(root, os.path.abspath(file))
            Files.setdefault(file, []).append(full_path)
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit the above code to be able to find files of the same name in separate directories?  Also would there be complications if two files had the same name, but different extensions in the same directory?

Comment: @WalterKovacs: you are already filtering on extension, so that's not going to be a problem. Use a list to store the full paths; `Files.setdefault(file, []).append(os.path.join(root, os.path.abspath(file)))` collects found paths into a list per filename.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs for os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join),

> If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on
>   Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are
>   thrown away

So, for example, if the second argument is an absolute path, the first path, `'/a/b/c'` is discarded.

```
In [14]: os.path.join('/a/b/c', '/d/e/f')
Out[14]: '/d/e/f'
```

Therefore,

```
os.path.join(root, os.path.abspath(file))
```

will discard `root` no matter what it is, and return `os.path.abspath(file)` which will tack `file` on to the current working directory, which will not necessarily be the same as `root`.

Instead, to form the absolute path to the file:

```
fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Actually, I believe the `os.path.abspath` is unnecessary, since I believe `root` will always be absolute, but my reasoning for that depends on [the source code for `os.walk`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8ee2b73cda7a/Lib/os.py#l292) not just the documented (guaranteed) behavior of `os.walk`. So to be absolutely sure (pun intended), use `os.path.abspath`.

---

```
import os
samefiles = {}
root = os.getcwd()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.c'):
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, file)
            samefiles.setdefault(file, []).append(fullpath) 

print(samefiles)
```

Answer (score -1):

Glob is useful in these cases, you can do:

```
files = {f:os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f) for f in glob.glob("*.c")}
```

to get the same result

Comment: Glob doesn't traverse subdirectories. You'd still have to use `os.walk()`, in which case you could use `fnmatch` to filter the filenames, but for a simple suffix test the `filename.endswith('.c')` test is just fine.